# Specify number of bins in hist() in R?

Tags: r

I try to specify number of bins in `hist()` in R to be 10, as follows

```
> hist(x, breaks=10)
```

But the number of bins is not exactly 10. I try several with other numbers of bins, and same thing happen.

`?hist` says `breaks` can specify

> a single number giving the number of cells for the histogram.

So I wonder what I can do now? Thanks!

Comment: You should read the whole documentation. "In the last three cases the number is a suggestion only; the breakpoints will be set to pretty values." You can pass a vector of breakpoints if you want the exact values as breaks.

Comment: I get exactly 10 bins in `hist(rnorm(100), breaks = 10)`. However, if I do `hist(c(rnorm(100), 5), breaks = 10)`, I get fewer than 10 because there are certain ranges along the x for which there is no data. Maybe this is what happens to you.

Comment: @Roland: if I specify breaks to be 600, will there likely to be 500 bins?

Answer (score 2):

You can always create custom breakpoints

```
x   = rnorm(500)
brks = seq(-3,3,0.1)
hist(x, breaks = brks)
```

Comment: Thanks! a side question, if I use the same name as the formal argument for the actual argument, is it correct that it always work? E.g. `breaks = seq(-3,3,0.1); hist(x, breaks = breaks)`?

Comment: I have tried your approach before I posted the question. The problem with that is I specified `brks = seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=500)`, but `hist(x, breaks = brks)` complained that some entries of `x` wouldn't be included in the histogram. So what would you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Tim wrote in comments:

> The problem with that is I specified brks = seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=500), but hist(x, breaks = brks) complained that some entries of x wouldn't be included in the histogram

I had the same problem. I suspect this happens because the value on the border of range is not counted. I have 2 solutions but non satisfies me in 100%.

Solution 1.
When making the sequence, set minimum a little bit lower and maximum a little bit higher.

```
brks = seq(min(x)*.99999,max(x)*1.00001,length.out=500)
```

Solution 2. Instead of hist() use a combination of cut() and barplot(). The plot looks almost the same as hist, but doesn't produce a data frame like hist().

```
barplot(summary(cut(data, 10)), space=0)
```