# hist function with single number breaks result in a larger than specified bins or intervals. Does anyone know why?

Tags: r

One of the `hist()` functions arguments is `breaks`.  It can be any one of many options one of them is a single number specifying the number of breaks.  In my example I specify the single number 10.

Why do I sometimes end up with more than 10 bins?  In this case 15 intervals instead of 10 which has a significant deviation of 50% over the number specified.

```
x <- c(98.75,97.92,98.80,98.14,98.95,98.30,98.98,98.47,99.41,98.92,99.25,99.07,99.73,
99.01,100.70,99.95)
findInterval(x,hist(x,10,plot=F)$breaks)
```

The result is:

```
[1] 5 1 5 2 6 3 6 4 9 6 8 7 10 7 15 11
```

I expected the max interval to be 10 not 15, can anyone explain the logic that resulted in 15 intervals although I specified the number 10 for breaks?

The question [Specify number of bins in hist() in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714398/specify-number-of-bins-in-hist-in-r) asked a similar question but I don't think his example was clear enough. One of the comments was, the 10 number specified for the bins is  a suggestion, it seems this is the closest answer to the truth, but I am not sure.

I don't necessarily have to have 10 bins, I can live with the 15, but I am trying to understand the logic so I would know what to expect when I use this function.

Comment: If you pass a single number this "is a suggestion only; the breakpoints will be set to `pretty` values". If you want exactly 10 bins you have to pass the exact breaks.

Comment: Ok thanks that confirms it

Comment: @Roland, post as answer?

Comment: Just a clarification comment, when you said pretty earlier I didn't realize pretty() was a function.  I thought you meant pretty as in a nice number, like a good guess or something.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a single number to the `breaks` parameter, `hist` uses `pretty` to calculate the breaks:

```
x <- c(98.75,97.92,98.80,98.14,98.95,98.30,98.98,98.47,99.41,98.92,99.25,99.07,99.73,
       99.01,100.70,99.95)
length(pretty(range(x), n = 10, min.n = 1))
#[1] 16
#== 15 bins

identical(hist(x, breaks=10)$breaks,
          pretty(range(x), n = 10, min.n = 1))
#[1] TRUE
```

You need to pass explicit break values to `hist` if you want to have an exact number of bins:

```
length(hist(x, breaks = seq(min(x), max(x), length.out=11))$breaks)
#[1] 11
```

This is documented in `help("hist")`:

> **breaks**
>
> one of:
>
> a vector giving the breakpoints between histogram cells,
>
> a function to compute the vector of breakpoints,
>
> a single number giving the number of cells for the histogram,
>
> a character string naming an algorithm to compute the number of cells
>   (see ‘Details’),
>
> a function to compute the number of cells.
>
> In the last three cases the number is a suggestion only; the
>   breakpoints will be set to pretty values. If breaks is a function, the
>   x vector is supplied to it as the only argument.